# Meromorphic interpolation of number-theoretic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-continuation, interpolation-theory, weierstrass-factorization

A meromorphic interpolation of the harmonic numbers is given by
\begin{align}
H_n
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^1 x^k \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \,\mathrm{d}{x} \\
&= \gamma + \psi(n+1)
\end{align}
where $\psi$ is the digamma function. A meromorphic interpolation of the factorial numbers is given by the gamma function $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$. Is there a meromorphic interpolation of number-theoretic functions like the prime indicator function $\chi_\mathbb{P}$, prime-counting function $\pi$, and Möbius function $\mu$? Perhaps through the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276308/number-theoretic-functions) might be related (since binomial coefficients can be easily [extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments) to continuous values).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\text{sinc}(x)=  \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ which is entire and vanishes at every non-zero integer.

If for some $k$, $|f(n)|\le C (n!)^k $ then 
$$F_{k+1}(x) = \Gamma(x)^{k+1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{(n!)^{k+1}} \text{sinc}(x-n)$$
is analytic away from negative integers and 
 $$ F_{k+1}(n) = f(n) , \qquad n \ge 1$$

A much more difficult question is if there exists an interpolating function not only analytic in a region but also satisfying some decay conditions, in which case it can be unique or non-existing, see Ramanujan master theorem.

Not sure if there are interpolation better suited for multiplicative functions such as $\mu(n)$. For example the inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)/\zeta(s)$ is $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) e^{-nz}$ and $G(u)= e^u\int_0^1 g(1+2i\pi y) e^{2i \pi u y}dy = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(2+it)}{\zeta(2+it)} (\int_0^1 e^{(1+2i \pi y) u}(1+2i \pi y)^{-2-it}du) dt$ satisfies $G(n) = \mu(n)$